# Visual Studio 2015 Selenium issue

Tags: selenium, visual-studio-2015

Was trying to set up a regression test suite using Selenium and Visual Studio 2015.
I created a regular Unit Test Project ( MS TEST) and also installed Selenium.WebDriver(V2.48.2) using NuGet

I have a simple test file

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;

namespace SampleProject
{
   [TestClass]
   public class UnitTest1
   {
     static IWebDriver driverFF;        

     [AssemblyInitialize]
     public static void SetUp(TestContext context)
     {
        driverFF = new FirefoxDriver();
     }

     [TestMethod]
     public void TestMethod1()
     {            
        driverFF.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
     }
  }
}
```

But I get this error. Any pointers?

```
Result StackTrace:  
at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
at OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.Internal.Executable.LocateFirefoxBinaryFromPlatform()
at OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.Internal.Executable..ctor(String userSpecifiedBinaryPath)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxBinary..ctor(String pathToFirefoxBinary)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver..ctor()
at SampleProject.UnitTest1.SetUp(TestContext context) in C:\Selenium\SampleProject\UnitTest1.cs:line 17
```

Comment: Do I need to make my driver point to the path where firefox is installed?

Comment: There seems to be an issue opened in github          https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/1431

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a bug opened against this for the firefox browser https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/1431                                  It works well if one is using the chrome driver. One just needs to give the path to the chrome driver in the constructor. The chrome driver can be found here http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.20/ . Note just give the path to the parent directory where this driver is stored                                    driverChrome = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\Selenium\Libs\");